# Ajax error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, servlets

I have a servlet in java.

My servlet URL is **http: //192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/UserClickPersonClassifier?userid=1&query=asp.net**

This URL is giving json data.

I am using a jquery ajax call to get the data.

**My Code**

```
function SecondResultLink(link, userId, userInput) {
try{
    var urlSearch = "http://192.168.10.113:8080/collective-intellegence/UserClickLinkClassifier?userid=" + userId + "&query=" + userInput;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlSearch,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                    if (!link.exist(data[index].Link.name.toLowerCase(), data[index].Score)) {
                        link.add(data[index].Link.name.toLowerCase(), data[index].Score);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.error);
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err);
}
}
```

the above code is giving 45 records in Chrome,Firefox and Safari but giving 25 records in Opera and giving error message in IE.

Error Message in IE:- **function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?
k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))} return this}**

In all browser except IE request is going to server, but in IE not request is going to the server.

This is not a cross domain problem because i allowed all to access the server(seen in the header that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)

What is problem with IE? 
how to solve this issue or any other approach to get the data.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: You JS code is not working on IE, not the servlet.

Comment: I placed a alert inside the function.Its working fine.
You are saying that ajax is not working here.

what should I add to work the JS.
please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 and IE9 is not fully support cors..
so you will have to write some code specific for ie 8 and 9

Go through this link
This will help you
(Click here)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx]